# Maintain a git repository in all dask.distributed worker / scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

What would be the best way for all Dask (distributed) workers / schedulers to understand a custom git repository's python modules?

It would be a plus if the new commits to the git repository are reflected on the Dask workers / schedulers the same way.

I have tried the following things:

(1) Using client.upload_file API, copy the files from master node to worker nodes. Copying the files individually loses the module / directory structure so zipping the files then uploading that could work. But updates to the git repository wouldn't be reflected in the zipped repositories of master and worker nodes.

(2) (From Amazon EMR) In the bootstrap script, I included "pip install git+https://github.com/my_repo.git", so that all nodes would have the repository upon cluster instantiation. But same as (1); updates to the git repository wouldn't be reflected in the installed packages under site-packages/.

Comment: Sorry, but this is rather unclear and broad, please try to be more specific with what you are trying to do and, ideally, anything you've attempted so far.

Comment: @mdurant I have updated the question with what I've attempted so far.

Comment: I'm using a combination of rsync (to copy my git checkout to workers) and ansible (to manage the environment, with its pip module).

Answer (score 0):

Dask does not manage user software environments.  Typically people handle this with Docker images or Network File Systems (NFS)

Comment: For docker - would it be something like, updates to the source repository triggers a new deployment of docker image and restarting the instances running dask schedulers / workers in a cluster?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  Unfortunately I am not a docker expert, and so may not be able to provide you with advice here.  Good luck!